# multiprocessing.Pool using map() behaves extremely slow with a large List input

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When I compute function outputs with a mass of independent varying inputs, I used Pool for parallel computing and wrote code like

```
num_cores = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
with Pool(processes=num_cores) as pool:
    results = pool.map(myfunc, xlist)
```

where xlist = [x1,x2,...,xn] is the input list.

This code goes pretty well with a short xlist as expected, but behaves extremely slow when input list gets large. What I actually mean is that the performance would degenerate sharply.

For example, if this code takes only T (second) for a list with length==10, then it take about 10*T for a 10*length list, and 100*T for a 100*length list. However, it may take 50000*T or even much more time for a 1000*T length list (My computer has a large enough memory storage).

Currently I split the long list into multiple short sub-lists piece by piece and make a success in avoiding the degeneration. But I wonder why this bizarre situation could happen. What should I do to directly feed the long list into the pool without any performance degeneration?

Comment: can you show your myfunc ? how are you using value xlist in that?

Comment: the complete function is too complex to post. It receives an 8-element tuple as input, assigns local variables according to the tuple, then computes and finally returns a result. Every element in xlist is hence a tuple. Some elements' types in the tuple are self-defined class.

Comment: it might be simply caused by the complexity of your function, plus if the function is communicating with HDD/SSD, over internet and so on the speed might be very limited even for the parallel processing

Comment: yes the function is somehow complex, inside which lots iterations and lists are used. But no such communication is involved. No interaction with IO or other processes. It's a pure logical and computational function. @Ruli

Comment: You are passing xlist to myfunc ..and myfunc should be like to process single element (say x1) in xlist.

Comment: thank you. but actually that's what I did, and the strange point is that such an xlist with ~thousand elements works well but a much longer xlist doesn't. If the way I deliver the parameters has been wrong, any xlist would have failed regardless of its length; If it has been some certain element in xlist that caused the degeneration, the piece-by-piece splitting should not have help. If my CPU capability was the bottleneck, why hasn't the CPU run out until the pool handled ~thousand times of functions?